# A macro for defining macros and invoke them sequentially (Tex)

Tags: macros, tex-core, definition

Briefly,

In Pure Tex

```
% THE FIRST ARGUMENT SHOULDN'T NEED TO RECEIVE \ AS FIRST CHARACTER
\global\def\futuredef#1#2{\global\def\#1{#2}#2}
\futuredef{love}{doesn't exist}
\love % Gives a error!
```

and

```
% THE FIRST ARGUMENT NEED TO RECEIVE \ AS FIRST CHARACTER
\global\def\futuredef#1#2{\global\def#1{#2}#2}
\futuredef\love{exists}
\love % Works fine
```

How to make the first version of "futuredef" operational? If I want to use the recent created macro, how can I invoke it in the same macro (which had just defined it)?
For example

```
\global\def\futuredef#1#2{\global\def#1{#2}\csname#1\endcsname}
%but doesn't work!!! generates prematurely a error when running it (OUTPUT: Missing $ ) -- WHAT HELL!?!?!
\futuredef\love{exists}
\love % and fails again!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say:

> How to make the first version of "futuredef" operational? If I want to
> use the recent created macro, how can I invoke it in the same macro
> (which had just defined it)? For example
>
> ```
> \global\def\futuredef#1#2{\global\def#1{#2}\csname#1\endcsname}
> %but doesn't work!!! generates prematurely a error when running it (OUTPUT: Missing $ ) -- WHAT HELL!?!?!
> \futuredef\love{exists}
> \love % and fails again!
> ```

If I got you right, `\futuredef` shall both define and call a macro when only a sequence of tokens denoting the name of the macro, not the macro-token itself, is provided.

You are almost there!

You already have `\csname#1\endcsname` in your code for producing the control sequence token from its name.
You need to have TeX apply `\csname..\endcsname` before performing `\def`, too—otherwise `\def` is not applied to the to-be-defined control sequence token but to the first token of the token-sequence that denotes the name of the to-be-defined control sequence token. And this will not work out because with `\def` TeX expects a control sequence token, not its name.
Of course `\futuredef` will then as its first argument process the name of the control sequence token, not the control sequence token itself:

```
\global\def\futuredef#1#2{\global\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}\csname#1\endcsname}
%Let's both globally define and call \love:
\futuredef{love}{\message{love exists}}%
%Let's call \love again:
\love % This does not fail. ;-)
\bye
```

(Producing .pdf files is something I sometimes get stingy with. ;-) So I decided to have `\love` defined as a macro that produces a `\message` because this way no .pdf-file is created and you on the console see anyway that something happens.)

Console-output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex love exists love exists )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

But this approach does not let you provide *⟨parameter text⟩* with definitions provided in terms of `\futuredef`. Thus with this approach you can use `\futuredef` only for defining macros that do not process arguments/argument-delimiters.

---

---

Defining and immediately calling a macro makes perfect sense to me also in situations where the newly defined macro is to process arguments which follow the `\futuredef`-macro. In order to take parameter-text into account I suggest `#{`-syntax:

*Additional remarks in November 21, 2020:*

*In a comment you asked for clarification what `#{`-notation is about:*

*Your variant of `\futuredef` is not designed to define (and call immediately after defining) macros that process arguments/parameters `#1`, `#2`, ...

Your intended syntax is:*

```
\futuredef{⟨macro name⟩}{⟨definition text⟩}
```

*I have extended it so that you can also do:*

```
\futuredef{⟨macro name}⟩#1#2..#9{⟨definition text⟩}
\futuredef{⟨macro name⟩}⟨parameter text⟩{⟨definition text⟩}
```

*For this have `\futuredef` process besides its first argument (which holds  *⟨macro name⟩*) a second argument which is delimited by the opening curly brace `{` of the *⟨definition text⟩* and which holds the tokens forming the *⟨parameter text⟩*:*

*In TeX there is the special case that the last argument of a macro, e.g., the second argument of the macro `\futuredef` below, is delimited by an opening curly brace if you write a `#` behind the *⟨parameter text⟩* of that macro's *⟨definition⟩*.
Since the opening curly brace of the *⟨definition text⟩* immediately follows that `#`, this is called `#{` syntax.*

*(Unlike other argument-delimiters such an opening curly brace will not be removed while gathering the arguments of the macro but it will be left in place and appear right behind the replacement text of that macro.)*

```
\long\def\futuredef#1#2#{%
  % #1 - tokens yielding character tokens forming the name of the to-be-defined control-sequence token
  % #2 - parameter text, delimited by { of the following definition-text
  \expandafter\innerfuturedef\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{#2}%
}%
\long\def\innerfuturedef#1#2#3{%
  % #1 - to-be-defined control-sequence token
  % #2 - parameter text
  % #3 - definition text
  \def#1#2{#3}% <- let's define #1
  #1% <- let's call #1
}%
% Now introduce a local scope:
\begingroup
% Now let's both globally define \macro to process 3 arguments and call \macro for processing the 3 arguments {A}{B}{C}:
\global\long\futuredef{macro}#1#2#3{\message{Arg1: #1, Arg2: #2, Arg3: #3}}{A}{B}{C}%
% Now close the local scope:
\endgroup
% Let TeX display on the console how `\macro` is defined:
\show\macro
% Now let's both define and call \macroB which does not take arguments:
\futuredef{macroB}{\message{A nice message.}}%
% Let TeX display on the console how `\macroB` is defined:
\show\macroB
\bye
```

Console output is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex Arg1: A, Arg2: B, Arg3: C
> \macro=\long macro:
#1#2#3->\message {Arg1: #1, Arg2: #2, Arg3: #3}.
l.20 \show\macro
                
? 
A nice message.
> \macroB=macro:
->\message {A nice message.}.
l.24 \show\macroB
                 
? 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

---

If you don't need prefixes like `\long` or `\global` or `\protected` or `\outer`, you can just use `\afterassignment`:

```
\long\def\futuredef#1{%
  % #1 - tokens yielding character tokens forming the name of the to-be-defined control-sequence token
  \expandafter\afterassignment\csname#1\endcsname 
  \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname 
}%
% Now let's both within the current scope define \macro to process 3 arguments and call \macro for processing the 3 arguments {A}{B}{C}:
\futuredef{macro}#1#2#3{\message{Arg1: #1, Arg2: #2, Arg3: #3}}{A}{B}{C}%
% Let TeX display on the console how `\macro` is defined:
\show\macro
\bye
```

Comment: First of all: why have you deleted that so amazing answer? The most complete description about the theme I could find and in a intensive and direct way! I've came back here to reread it again and to mark it as a best answer. If do you have a copy of it, write it again (there is no problem having to answers to a question from the same user, I believe).

Comment: You've showed me now that I was deeply wrong about how \def fields/arguments work. In a imaginary TeX exam about macro definitions, I would fail fatally. I have change the way I see some TeX features! Thank you a lot!!! (again, keep the last answer as a extra! That was really the best resume about how TeX digest tokens).

Comment: @DanielBandeira I deleted my previous answer because I realized that it was -eh- embarrassingly pointless: I elaborated excessively and enthusiastically on using `\expandafter` and a macro `\exchange` for expanding a `\csname..\endcsname`-expression to the corresponding control-sequence-token and getting that behind another sequence of tokens although all this was not necessary: The `\csname..\endcsname`-expression behind that "another sequence of tokens" is perfectly fine - it will deliver the corresponding control-word-token... No need for whatsoever `\expandafter`-`\exchange`-trickery...

Comment: @DanielBandeira When thinking about how  TeX digests TeX-input, it often is sufficient to play the "eyes"-"mouth"-"gullet"-"stomach"-game. ;-) Details are spread over the TeXbook. ;-)  Eyes look at the .tex-input-file line by line and put characters (not tokens yet) into the mouth. The mouth forms so-called tokens from the characters and sends them towards the gullet. The gullet expands expandable tokens unless under special circumstances and sends the result to the stomach where further processing takes place. (Performing assignments, e.g. `\def`. Creating boxes. Placing ...

Comment: @DanielBandeira ... Placing boxes on the page. Shipping out the full page to the .pdf-file that gets created. Performing `\write` to external text file...) Each station works when the station that comes after it requires it to do so. And most of the time it only works as much as it absolutely has to.  I elaborated on TeX's digestion-processes in more detail, e.g. in my answer to [Conversion of space characters into space tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516129/118714) and in my answer to [Define commands without the need for brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552175/118714)

Comment: Thank you again! Only now, after some months, the things are starting to make a deeper sense. You are really fluent in TeX. Great Job!

Comment: @DanielBandeira "... a deeper sense..."   YMMD ;-))))

Comment: I don't get yet how the entire paramter text has been passed to the macro in definition process. You've written "In order to take parameter-text into account I suggest #{-syntax". What have you meant with that?

Comment: @DanielBandeira I just added a few remarks to my answer in the hope that they will shed some light on some of your questions. If my explanations are not sufficient don't hesitate to let me know and I will try to do better. ;-)

Comment: Thank you too much! I'm in your debt!